# Send Email in Angular Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, email

I am trying send a email with html body on click of button I am using Angular 10.0.8
is there any possible way to send email using SMTP Relay in typescript without using nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like **email.js** or **smtp.js**

With smtp.js you can

```
Email.send({
    SecureToken : "C973D7AD-F097-4B95-91F4-40ABC5567812",
    To : 'them@website.com',
    From : "you@isp.com",
    Subject : "This is the subject",
    Body : "And this is the body"
}).then(
  message => alert(message)
);
```

The security key is generated on the website and is different for your credentials

but this only supports Elasticmail securely at this time
[smtpjs.com for documentation](https://www.smtpjs.com/)

and email.js is a paid service

Comment: I tried the above i followed the tutorials from here           https://javascript.plainenglish.io/send-emails-without-a-server-side-code-with-angular-e227c3e62dbd    I have an Elasticmail api  but still it doesnt work I get Email is undefined , cannot get reference of send in console

Comment: @SteveMiller I get the same error saying Email is undefined, by-chance have you fixed this issue? if yes can you please let me know how you have done it?